# Install Delphi 5 for Windows 10

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-5, bde

I tried to install Delphi 5 on Windows 10, but hangs when configuring the BDE.

I've tried in a different directory with administrator permissions.

I've tried for compatibility mode as well.

If someone knows , I am very grateful!

[This image is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7LDL.png)

Comment: You would be better off setting up a VM running a version of Windows that Delphi 5 supports, than to try to install such an old IDE into a modern OS.

Comment: If you don't REALY REALY REALY  need BDE, then don't install it. I have a Delphi 6 running on a Windows 10 without problems.

Comment: I have two legacy application that depends on some libraries Delphi 5 , I must migrate to a new version.

Comment: Um, your screenshot doesn't seem to show any error at all; do you mean that the install just hangs? What I'd do in these circs would be to omit the BDE from the D5 install, then transplant the BDE folder + files + its reg keys from a machine you have it working on. Btw, you may run into permissions problems if you try installing in the various places Win10 doesn't like files to be written at r/t.

Comment: it was a problem to even install D5 to WinXP...

I am not sure that would solve your problem, but I verily suggest you to do it!  1) do not install D5 into Program Files. In 1999 no one thought about UAC. Make a special folder like C:\Delphi and during installation change all the paths, including BDE to into subfolders point there. Remove or change user-specific %TEMP% and %TMP% environment vars introduced in XP. Make them both have a short imple value like C:\Temp or C:\windows\temp and ensure installing user has r/w access to that path

Comment: I will try that - Arioch

Comment: @MartynA If you try to not install the BDE, the installer will tell you that the options you have chosen require the BDE, and the BDE will be installed anyway.

Answer (score 8):

This is the procedure I use to install Delphi 5 Pro on Windows 10:

- Log in as Administrator
- Turn UAC off
- Log in as Standard User
- Install Delphi 5 Pro via installer
- The installation hangs while trying to install the BDE.
- Use Task Manager to kill the install process.
- Delete C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi 5\Uninst.isu
- Install Delphi 5 Pro via installer
- Select registry settings only.
- Install d5proupgrade.exe (Bug fix Upgrade for Delphi 5 Pro)
- Open a command prompt as Administrator:

  `> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Borland Shared\Debugger`

  `> tregsvr bordbk50.dll`

  `> cd C:\see\below\regarding\winhlp32-windows-7-x86-x86-komeil`

  `> Install.cmd`
- Edit permission on C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi5\Bin\delphi32.dro adding Everyone with Full Control
- Start Delphi 5
- When prompted, don't change JIT debugger and check don't ask again.
- Close Delphi 5
- Turn UAC on.

I don't use the BDE and have never tested to see if it works or not after this procedure.

See http://www.komeil.com/blog/windows-help-program-winhelp-winhlp32-exe to find out how to get Delphi 5 Help working in Windows 10 and to obtain winhlp32-windows-7-x86-x64-komeil.cab. You'll have to download and extract the cab file then edit the Install.cmd, adding the last two line in the Settings so it reads:

```
:: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Settings

set MuiFileName=winhlp32.exe.mui
set ExeFileName=winhlp32.exe
set WindowsVersion=7
goto :BypassVersionError
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem but I found a workaround.

1. Install BDE from a separate source (for example you can download it from the EDN)
2. Start installing Delphi 5
3. When it stuck on the Configuring BDE screen open Task manager and close the installer with the End task.
4. Start the installer again but choose the latest option to setting Registry only.
5. Enjoy (?)